в чем проблема помогите
я рисую диалог.написал в draw gui вот это
draw_sprite(sp_dialogue_box, -1, 0,224)
draw_text(163,240, global.diagchar)
draw_text(163,270,global.diagphrase)

выдает
ERROR in
action number 1
of Draw Event
for object ob_dialog:

global variable name 'diagchar' index (100005) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Object_ob_dialog_Draw_64 (line 4) - draw_text(163,240, global.diagchar)

gml_Object_ob_dialog_Draw_64 (line 4)
когда я нажимаю на английскую T должно нарисовать диалог

Обращаетесь к переменным до или после их обьявления? Что насчет области видимости переменных?
